# error: ‘Imag’ does not name a type

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to C++ and I am writing a program to add two complex number:

here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef IMAGINE_H
#define IMAGINE_H

#include<iostream>
using std::ostream;

class Imag{
public:
  double real;
  double imag;

  Imag() = default;
  Imag(double,double);

  Imag add(Imag);
};

#endif
```

and here is my .cpp file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"imagine.h"
using namespace std;

Imag::Imag(){
  this-> real;
  this-> imag;

}
Imag  Imag:: add(Imag i){
  Imag result = new Image();
  result -> real = this->real + i -> real;
  result -> imag = this-> imag + i-> imag;
  return result;
}
```

When compiling, it complains like this:

```
imagine.cpp:5:1: error: ‘Imag’ does not name a type
 Imag::Imag(){
 ^
imagine.cpp:10:1: error: ‘Imag’ does not name a type
 Imag  Imag:: add(Imag i){
 ^
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks so much!

Comment: You need a `;` at the end of the class declaration.

Comment: Once you've fixed that, read about the difference between objects an pointers, and get rid of that evil `new`.

Comment: Would it even compile ? What would be the signification of assigning the result of new to an object ? :\

Comment: This should be rolled back as the OP just invalidated the answer.

Comment: @Jamal but I am only building class here not two...

Answer (score 4):

You did not end the class declaration with a semi-colon. This is the proper syntax.

`class ClassName { /* */ };`

Comment: I do have semi colon in my program. I just forgot to paste it.

Comment: @NobWong: We would not have known otherwise.  Do you still get the same errors?

Comment: Seriously ?! Twice ?! Make sure the code is *EXACTLY* as it is in your IDE now.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is exactly the same now.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem, I get different errors:

```
$ cat imagine.h
#ifndef IMAGINE_H
#define IMAGINE_H

#include<iostream>
using std::ostream;

class Imag{
public:
  double real;
  double imag;

  Imag() = default;
  Imag(double,double);

  Imag add(Imag);
};

#endif
$ cat imagine.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"imagine.h"
using namespace std;

Imag::Imag(){
  this-> real;
  this-> imag;

}
Imag  Imag:: add(Imag i){
  Imag result = new Image();
  result -> real = this->real + i -> real;
  result -> imag = this-> imag + i-> imag;
  return result;
}
$ g++ -c -W -Wall -s -O2 imagine.cpp
In file included from imagine.cpp:2:
imagine.h:12: warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
imagine.cpp: In constructor ‘Imag::Imag()’:
imagine.cpp:6: warning: statement has no effect
imagine.cpp:7: warning: statement has no effect
imagine.cpp: In member function ‘Imag Imag::add(Imag)’:
imagine.cpp:11: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Image’
imagine.cpp:11: error: conversion from ‘int*’ to non-scalar type ‘Imag’ requested
imagine.cpp:11: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘Image’
imagine.cpp:12: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Imag’
imagine.cpp:12: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Imag’
imagine.cpp:13: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Imag’
imagine.cpp:13: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Imag’
```

Here is how to fix them:

```
$ cat imagine.h
#ifndef IMAGINE_H
#define IMAGINE_H

#include<iostream>
using std::ostream;

class Imag{
public:
  double real;
  double imag;

  Imag();
  Imag(double,double);

  Imag add(Imag);
};

#endif
$ cat imagine.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"imagine.h"
using namespace std;
Imag::Imag(): real(0), imag(0) {}
Imag::Imag(double r, double i): real(r), imag(i) {}
Imag Imag::add(Imag i){
  Imag result;
  result.real = real + i.real;
  result.imag = imag + i.imag;
  return result;
}
$ g++ -c -W -Wall -s -O2 imagine.cpp
(No errors or warnings.)
```

There are many other ways to improve the code, for example, `add` could take a `const Imag&` instead, and we don't need `#include <iostream>` or `using namespace std;`. It's also a good idea to make `real` and `imag` private, and introduce public reader methods.

Comment: Hi thanks! But i don't really understand this part of the code:Imag::Imag(): real(0), imag(0) {}
Imag::Imag(double r, double i): real(r), imag(i) {} Could you explain this to me?

Comment: These are constructor definitions. Between the `:` and the `{` is the initialization list. If you don't understand them, read the chapter about initialization lists of your favourite C++ book or web tutorial (or ask it as a separate question on Stack Overflow.)